# Convert datatime and insert in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, datetime, type-conversion

I have to import a CVS file containing 120k rows. The first 6 columns contain the date and time separately, ie: year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds.

I imported them into Java:

```
int year = 2016
int month = 5
int day = 23
int hour = 15
int minutes = 57
int seconds = 22
```

How can I convert this format to a format compatible with MySQL (DATETIME)?

I also have a GMT column, i.e. "GMT +0200". Can I convert this data too in a DATETIME?

Comment: What is the [data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) of the column? `DATETIME`? `TIMESTAMP`?

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do this is to build your string in this format:

yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

Then insert it.

INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES('2016-05-23 15:57:22')

Answer (score 2):

```
String datetime = String.format("%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds);
```

That will produce you a `DATETIME`

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    ZonedDateTime.of( 2016 , 5 , 23 , 15 , 57 , 22 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) )
) ;
```

## Details

Using [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes with a [driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) supporting [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later for a [MySQL 5.7 `TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) column…

## Time zone

Determine your time zone intended for that date-time. **A date-time has no exact meaning without a time zone.** For example, noon in Paris France arrives much earlier than noon in Montréal Québec.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

## `ZonedDateTime` & `Instant`

Use your inputs along with the time zone to instantiate a `ZonedDateTime` to represent a moment on the timeline.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2016 , 5 , 23 , 15 , 57 , 22 , 0 , z ) ;
```

Extract the same moment as a value in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Send to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

And retrieve.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: This is in every way the preferred way. Using data-time types rather than strings tells the reader what you are dealing with and it gives you data validation for free. The advantages can hardly be over-estimated. And most important, the code is a bit more easlily readable.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I see only now that i have a column in the csv where is stored a "GMT" value, i.e. "GMT +0200". Is this a converted time zone? Or not?

Comment: Yes it is, or more precisely, a time zone offset (in many time zones, the offset varies over the year and/or has been changed historically and is likely to be again in the future). You should probably find a way to parse it.

Comment: @Simon, `ZoneOffset.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'GMT' xx").parse("GMT +0200"))` gives you a `ZoneOffset` object that you may use in constructing an `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: @Simon Edit your Question to include all the pertinent details, and I'll update my Answer to show the use of `OffsetDateTime` class. And, in the future, try to be more thorough and better prepared with all your details worked out *before* posting here as Stack Overflow is meant to be more formal, more like Wikipedia, than a casual discussion board. And respond to my comment on your Question by editing your Question to document the data type of your column.

Comment: @Basil Bourque You're right, sorry. I edited my question just now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I (too) recommend you use `java.time` for this. Since you have an offset from UTC (for our purpose UTC and GMT can be considered equivalent), declare a formatter for parsing it:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter gmtOffsetFormatter 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'GMT' xx");
```

Then create an `OffsetDateTime` object:

```
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.from(gmtOffsetFormatter.parse(gmtOffsetString));
    OffsetDateTime dateTime 
            = OffsetDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, 0, offset);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Perhaps not surprisingly this prints

```
2016-05-23T15:57:22+02:00
```

As I understand, your database column has datatype `datetime`, which doesn’t allow the offset to be stored. You may want to consider a `timestamp` column instead. For the `datetime`, you at least need to know (or decide) at which offset or in which time zone to interpret the database values. To convert your date-times to your decided database offset:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTimeWithoutOffset = dateTime
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toLocalDateTime();
```

I have taken UTC as a typical and recommended example. I am converting to `LocalDateTime` because I think this is the appropriate type to store into a `datetime` column, but this is not my home field, I might be mistaken. The snippet results in `2016-05-23T13:57:22`, which is the UTC equivalent of our datetime. To store into the database, follow [Basil Bourque’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47956224/5772882). `PreparedStatement.setObject()` is happy to accept a `LocalDateTime`.

If you can change the column type to `timestamp`, store an `Instant` into it as also shown in Basil Bourque’s answer.

```
    Instant inst = dateTime.toInstant();
```

The result is `2016-05-23T13:57:22Z` because `Instant.toString()` produces a string in UTC. The advantage of `timestamp` and `Instant` are that they denote unambiguous points on the time line, so neither you nor the people maintaining your code need worry any further about time zones or offsets.